# Deleting a line from a file in Python

Tags: python, string, file, line

I'm trying to delete a specific line that contains a specific string.

I've a file called **numbers.txt** with the following content:

> peter
>   tom
>   tom1
>   yan

What I want to delete is that **tom** from the file, so I made this function:

```
def deleteLine():
fn = 'numbers.txt'
f = open(fn)
output = []
for line in f:
    if not "tom" in line:
        output.append(line)
f.close()
f = open(fn, 'w')
f.writelines(output)
f.close()
```

The output is:

> peter
>   yan

As you can see, the problem is that the function delete **tom** and **tom1**, but I don't want to delete **tom1**. I want to delete just **tom**. This is the output that I want to have:

> peter
>   tom1
>   yan

Any ideas to change the function to make this correctly?

Comment: @Jakob Bowyer: Because `line` comes with the the newline so you'd need `line == 'tom\n'` or `line.rstrip() == 'tom'`, at least.

Comment: Please please please please search.  This question has been asked a dozen times.  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+delete+line+from+file.  Or.  If you question is about matching a line in  a file, please change the title to "string matching problem".  Or "why doesn't `not "tom" in line` work?"  Or something more focused and exact.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fastest Way to Delete a Line from Large File in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329417/fastest-way-to-delete-a-line-from-large-file-in-python)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

change the line:

```
    if not "tom" in line:
```

to:

```
    if "tom" != line.strip():
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to strip a line iterated from a fileobj.

Comment: Python 2.5.4 on Mac doesn't strip new lines chars when iterating a fileobj, so if you want to compare to a string, you need to strip it. Also I've seen many bugs after a whitespace somehow managed to sneak at the end of line and the code didn't handle it.

Comment: How very strange, both win and linux seem to strip without complaint, thanks for teaching me something :)

Comment: @Jakob Bowyer: For completeness, that's not true. Lines are not stripped in linux or windows either. Any lines read from a file object in python come **with the newline**, regardless of platform

Answer (score 4):

That's because

```
if not "tom" in line
```

checks, whether `tom` is not a substring of the current `line`. But in `tom1`, `tom` *is* a substring. Thus, it is deleted.

You probably could want one of the following:

```
if not "tom\n"==line # checks for complete (un)identity
if "tom\n" != line # checks for complete (un)identity, classical way
if not "tom"==line.strip() # first removes surrounding whitespace from `line`
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to strip a line when iterating directly over a fileobj, it should hand you stripped strings already.

Comment: @Jakob Bowyer: No, that's wrong. You **do** need to strip the line when iterating over a fileobj. It will yield lines **with the newline** so if you don't strip the strings won't compare equal.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, here's a two-liner to do it.

```
lines = filter(lambda x:x[0:-1]!="tom", open("names.txt", "r"))
open("names.txt", "w").write("".join(lines))
```

Challenge: someone post a one-liner for this.

You could also use the fileinput module to get arguably the most readable result:

```
import fileinput
for l in fileinput.input("names.txt", inplace=1):
    if l != "tom\n": print l[:-1]
```

Comment: ``open("names_out.txt", "w").write("\n".join(line for line in open("names.txt", "r") if line[:-1] != "tom"))``. I guess it won't work when the two filenames are identical, though.

Comment: Whoops. Should be ``"".join`` instead of ``"\n".join`` above. And I guess the in-place transformation can also be achieved using the ``fileinput`` module.

Comment: Something like `subprocess.Popen("sed -i '' -e'/^tom$/d' numbers.txt")` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex.

```
import re
if not re.match("^tom$", line):
    output.append(line)
```

The `$` means the end of the string.

Comment: If you go down that route you also need to match the start of the string i.e., ``re.match("^tom$", line)``.

Comment: @tzot, you were no less guilty of not fixing it than riza.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare, you're guilty of mistaken presumptions. *I* never believed he should edit it, given he used `.match` and not `.search`; my statement was a simple “if-then” nudge in response to riza's commenting and not editing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new in programing and python (a few months)... this is my solution:

```
import fileinput

c = 0 # counter
for line in fileinput.input("korrer.csv", inplace=True, mode="rb"):
    # the line I want to delete
    if c == 3: 
        c += 1
        pass
    else:
        line = line.replace("\n", "")
        print line
        c +=1
```

I'm sure there is a simpler way, just it's an idea. (my English it's not very good looking!!)