# How to delete a tuple from a file in python

Tags: python, file, tuples, line

```
imp,2,6,7

ads,4,5,6

sfd,2,5,8
```

I have a text file that looks like this
I want to delete the line that has `imp` in it.

All the other methods I have seen to delete lines from files only work for single strings

Comment: And what have you tried so far? If you are stuck with some code we can help you? SO is not a code-writing or tutorial service

Comment: I've tried something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710067/deleting-a-specific-line-in-a-file-python

Comment: Please post the code of what you have tried so far. Posting links won't do anything for you. The easier you make for others to understand the problem and your code the better help you will get.

Comment: what have you tried so far? have your tried `string.find()` or `re.match()`?

Comment: @JamesRedfearn The only thing you need to do different from the answer in the other thread are to use "'imp' not in line" as the condition to not write the line back.

Comment: There is no `tuple`. There is just something that looks like the _representation_ of a `tuple`.

Answer (score 1):

Following this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947833/deleting-a-line-from-a-file-in-python), you can try this:

```
fn = 'Test.txt'
f = open(fn)
output = []
for line in f:
    if not "imp" in line:
        output.append(line)
f.close()
f = open(fn, 'w')
f.writelines(output)
f.close()
```

Result:

> ads,4,5,6
>
> sfd,2,5,8