# Search and replace a line in a .xml file in Python

Tags: python, regex, xml, replace

I need to read and replace a line in a .xml file. I tried almost everything that I could imagine based on [Search and replace a line in a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086/search-and-replace-a-line-in-a-file-in-python), also [How to search and replace text in a file using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140886/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-python).

Then as a second step I thought that it would be possible to remove the line and print the new line on top based on [Deleting a specific line in a file (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710067/deleting-a-specific-line-in-a-file-python), also [Deleting a line from a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947833/deleting-a-line-from-a-file-in-python).

Unfortunately nothing worked correctly for me. Either the script writes all lines as the same output or the format is not correct after writing.

Then I start reading closser questions such as [How to remove elements from XML using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593204/how-to-remove-elements-from-xml-using-python) but again it was not I was trying to get as a final output.

**Update:** By accident I deleted one line and the whole xml code was not able to be seen.

Sample of *.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <!-- [START gcm_permission] -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!-- Required permission for App measurement to run. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> <!-- [END gcm_permission] -->
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I am trying to remove the line `package="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart"` with another line e.g. `package="another.line"`

The code that I am using:

```
def str_replace(file_input, keyword, str_new):
    for line in fileinput.input(file_input, inplace=True):
        line = line.rstrip('\r\n')
        print line.replace(keyword, str_new)
    fileinput.close()
    return
```

But it does not work correctly it just finds the string in the line and replaces just the string.

Sample of desired *.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="sample.different.line"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <!-- [START gcm_permission] -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!-- Required permission for App measurement to run. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> <!-- [END gcm_permission] -->
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**Update 2:** Thanks to [Nelson Guaman Leiva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3407798/nelson-guaman-leiva) I have found a partial solution to my problem. I can manage to find and replace the string on the specific point of my file. My new problem is that I can not found a way to match after the `pattern=*whatever text here*`, I can only find and replace the whole word, I can not match and replace after the equal sign.

Sample of code based on new solution:

```
def find_and_replace(file_input, str_old, str_new):
    with open(file_input, 'r') as fr:
        xml_data = fr.read()
        xml_data = re.sub(r'{}=\"(.+?)\"'.format(str_old), str_new, xml_data)
    fr.closed
    return
```

**Update 3:** I forgot to include the writing part of the process in the file, the code is included under. I am not sure if this process is the fastest or more sufficient to read and write but it is one possible solution.

Sample of code:

```
def str_replace(self, file_input, str_old, str_new):
        with open(file_input, "r") as fr:
            xml_data = fr.read()
            xml_data = re.sub(r"{}=\"(.+?)\"".format(str_old), str_new, xml_data)
        fr.closed

        with open(file_input, "w") as fw:
            fw.write(xml_data)
        fw.closed

        self.replace_string = xml_data
        return self.replace_string
```

If I found a solution to my problem on how to match and replace everything after the `package=*whatever here*` because currently I replace the whole line, but at least it works as expected.

Thank you for your time and effort in advance.

Comment: Your example doesn't have a _"package="_ line in it. Your before and after examples are identical. And then you say _" it just finds the string in the line and replaces just the string."_ but all you wanted to do was replace the string... what's the problem?

Comment: You are absolutely right, I do not know how or why the data that I post do not include the package file. I will update the data in a few hours as I do not have access on my pc. (Thank you for pointing out my error, apologies for wasting your time).

Comment: @tdelaney Apologies again, the code is now fixed. I deleted one line and by accident the xml code was hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this for example.

```
import re
with open ("file.xml", "r") as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()

data = re.sub(r"android:name=\"android\.permission\.[A-Z\_]+", "xxxx", data)
print data
```

This will replace all the android.permission.TEXT to xxx.

you only have to replace that string.

Comment: Thanks Nelson, that would be very useful on my next step, but for the moment I am trying to update my package line. Please updated code. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: I am thinking maybe a regex something among the lines `data = re.sub(r"package=\"any.possible.text.combination.here]+", "xxxx", data)`. Maybe something like that would work. But I do not know exactly how to do it. The problem is that I do not know either the combination of character or the number of dots. The only thing that I know is that starts with `package="anything.here"`. So it need to much any combination between the double quotation. Again, thank you for your time and effort.