# How to write to specific position in file based on other lines in file efficiently in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to write to a text file in specific positions based on text in the file.
For example, a file may have the following lines:

```
user=dog:admin
user=cat:admin
user=giraffe:admin

user=elephant:moderator
user=bat:moderator
user=snake:moderator
```

A way to parse that is to open with the following code and write between them:

```
with open("testfile", "r+") as testfile:
    lines = testfile.readlines() #read lines into list from file
    testfile.truncate() #empty file of data
    role_index = [i for i, line in enumerate(lines) if 'moderator' in line][0] #find first instance where moderator appears
    lines.insert(role_index, 'user=dragon:moderator\n') #insert our new user into that position with a newline
    for line in lines:
        testfile.write(line) #write back into empty file and fill with our user list
```

The file I work with has the potential to grow to a size to be much too large to parse efficiently by that manner above. What I'm seeking is a way to read through the file line by line (in a CPU efficient manner, e.g. reading every line super fast in a massive log takes a toll on the CPU) without instituting a sleep call to preserve CPU resources and a way to preserve memory.

If there's a way to pull that off, that would make my day.

Comment: Have you tried making part of the file saying where the moderator part starts then just looping thought that. Then editing that part of the file.

Comment: I think I misunderstand you. Do you mean by setting a seek for the file to seek where moderators start, or as in similar to say a configuration [MODERATORS] would work in configparser?

Comment: Yeah it wasn't the clearest. My suggestion was that maybe on the first line of the file you could say what lines on the file the moderators block is. Then loop and insert then change the first line to the new vaules.

Comment: Try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49742962/how-to-insert-text-at-line-and-column-position-in-a-file It might help

Comment: I appreciate it a ton! I will use the fro.readline() towards the top of that and work down the file. That should work just fine. Thanks!