# How to delete line of large CSV file in place for upload to Postgres

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, csv, bigdata

I have a 102gb CSV file exported from MongoDB that I'm trying to upload to Postgres. The file contains ~55 million rows. I'm using `\copy` to upload. However, I get a carriage return error on line 47,867,184:

```
ERROR: unquoted carriage return found in data
HINT: Use quoted CSV field to represent carriage return.
CONTEXT: COPY reso_facts, line 47867184
```

To my knowledge, Postgres doesn't allow for skipping bad rows on import. Seems like I need to fix the file. Is there a way to delete a CSV row in-place using Python? I strongly prefer not to write the file to an external hard drive.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329417/fastest-way-to-delete-a-line-from-large-file-in-python/2330081#2330081) elegant solution for txt files:

```
import os
from mmap import mmap
def removeLine(filename, lineno):
    f=os.open(filename, os.O_RDWR)
    m=mmap(f,0)
    p=0
    for i in range(lineno-1):
        p=m.find('\n',p)+1
    q=m.find('\n',p)
    m[p:q] = ' '*(q-p)
    os.close(f)
```

But it errors out when fed a CSV: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`. Is there a way to modify the above for CSVs, or is there an alternative method entirely?

Comment: I'm assuming the answer is for Python 2. You can try add `b'...'` prefix to the strings: `b'\n'` and `b' '*(q-p)`

Comment: Thanks @AndrejKesely, that was exactly the issue. Never worked with Python 2 so missed that. Closing the question